# can i merge multiple pandas indexing with one?

Tags: pandas

For example, given a dataframe `df`, the original indexing was `df.iloc[::-1].iloc[6::7]`.

Can I replace the two indexes with one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use `df.iloc[-7::-7]`

Comment: Thanks! Why it’s -7::-7 instead of -6::-7

Comment: First you reverse your order, then slice from index `6`. Remember that `-1`-index corresponds with `0`-index of the reverse.

Comment: thanks a lot i realized i have a extra indexing. `df.iloc[::-1].iloc[6::7].iloc[:5]` is it possible merge the last one ?

Comment: ... so index `6` of the reverse corresponds to index `-7` of the forward array / dataframe.

Comment: `df.iloc[-7:-36:-7]`

Comment: `7 * (5-1) + 7 + 1` with first `7` being the step, second `7` the start.